# Vue.js method is undefined when called

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to build a chrome extension with Vue using Browserify, in my component file I am trying to call from the `mounted` method a method of the component called `animateBackground` but on the console it gives mean error, how do I call data and methods of the component?
The code:

```
export default {
      name: "app",
      data() {
        return {
          'message': "thgdfseaw"
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        chrome.storage.local.get("bingImage", function(output) {
          if (output != undefined || output != null) {
            console.log(this.message);
            this.animateBackground(output.bingImage.base64);
          }});
  },
  methods: {
    animateBackground(base64) {
      $("#app").animate({ opacity: 0 }, "slow", function() {
        $(this)
          .css({ "background-image": "url(" + base64 + ")" })
          .animate({ opacity: 1 });
      });
    }
  },
  components: {
    AppSection
  }
};
```

[image: This is what I see on chrome console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the callback is not your `vue` instance you can `console.log` it to see what is it. there is many workaround for this. one of which you can use es6 arrow function syntax, also you can declare a new variable and assign `this` outside the callback then call it with the variable, here is an example:

```
export default {
      name: "app",
      data() {
        return {
          'message': "thgdfseaw"
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        var _vue = this // << here
        chrome.storage.local.get("bingImage", function(output) {
          if (output != undefined || output != null) {
            console.log(_vue.message); // << then access it like this
            _vue.animateBackground(output.bingImage.base64);
          }});
  },
  methods: {
    animateBackground(base64) {
      $("#app").animate({ opacity: 0 }, "slow", function() {
        $(this)
          .css({ "background-image": "url(" + base64 + ")" })
          .animate({ opacity: 1 });
      });
    }
  },
  components: {
    AppSection
  }
};
```